# On click get button values from array javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, button

I have a function that creates a button for each value in an array. I want to get the value of the button that is clicked and store it in a variable.

```
dates_button = ['8/21/2020','8/28/2020','9/4/2020','9/11/2020','9/18/2020','9/25/2020','10/16/2020','11/19/2020','1/14/2021','3/19/2021','6/18/2021','9/17/2021','1/20/2022']

    function printBtn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dates_button.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dates_button[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
}

printBtn();
```

Comment: Where's your event listener code? Show us what you have tried. The objective here is for you to do the basic research and show your attempts to solve your own issue and people help when those attempts don't work as expected. The objective is not for others to write all the code for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event handler that reads back the `textContent` from the button; then you can do what you want with it in the event handler. For example:

```js
dates_button = ['8/21/2020', '8/28/2020', '9/4/2020', '9/11/2020', '9/18/2020', '9/25/2020', '10/16/2020', '11/19/2020', '1/14/2021', '3/19/2021', '6/18/2021', '9/17/2021', '1/20/2022']

function btnClick(e) {
  let date = e.target.textContent;
  // do something with it
  console.log(date);
}

function printBtn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dates_button.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dates_button[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    btn.onclick = btnClick;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
}

printBtn();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const dates_button = ['8/21/2020', '8/28/2020', '9/4/2020', '9/11/2020', '9/18/2020', '9/25/2020', '10/16/2020', '11/19/2020', '1/14/2021', '3/19/2021', '6/18/2021', '9/17/2021', '1/20/2022']

function printBtn() {
  for (let i = 0; i < dates_button.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let t = document.createTextNode(dates_button[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
      alert(dates_button[i]);
    });
  }
}

printBtn();
```

You don't even need to read the text out of the DOM if you just add the event listener in your loop there.

Or, if you prefer, this might be a little more efficient because it only requires one event listener.

```js
const dates_button = ['8/21/2020', '8/28/2020', '9/4/2020', '9/11/2020', '9/18/2020', '9/25/2020', '10/16/2020', '11/19/2020', '1/14/2021', '3/19/2021', '6/18/2021', '9/17/2021', '1/20/2022']

function printBtn() {
  for (let i = 0; i < dates_button.length; i++) {
    let btn = document.createElement("button");
    let t = document.createTextNode(dates_button[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
  }
}

document.addEventListener('click', (ev) => {
  if (ev.target.matches('button')) {
    console.log(ev.target.innerText);
  }
});

printBtn();
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `value` property on your `button` and attach an event listener. Then `onClick`'s event you can access the `value` as `event.target.value`.

```js
dates_button = [
  "8/21/2020",
  "8/28/2020",
  "9/4/2020",
  "9/11/2020",
  "9/18/2020",
  "9/25/2020",
  "10/16/2020",
  "11/19/2020",
  "1/14/2021",
  "3/19/2021",
  "6/18/2021",
  "9/17/2021",
  "1/20/2022"
];

function printBtn() {
  for (var i = 0; i < dates_button.length; i++) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var t = document.createTextNode(dates_button[i]);
    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);

    btn.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
    btn.value = dates_button[i];
  }
}

function handleClick(event) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}

printBtn();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function and use `onClick` function to get the value of a clicked date.

**Live Demo:**

```js
let dates_button = ['8/21/2020', '8/28/2020', '9/4/2020', '9/11/2020', '9/18/2020', '9/25/2020', '10/16/2020', '11/19/2020', '1/14/2021', '3/19/2021', '6/18/2021', '9/17/2021', '1/20/2022']

function printBtn() {
  dates_button.forEach(function(date) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode(date);
    btn.appendChild(text);
    btn.value = date;
    btn.onclick = function() {
      console.log(this.value)
    }
    document.querySelector('#el').appendChild(btn); //append all buttons
  })
}

printBtn();
```

```html
<div id="el"></div>
```